# How can I run an SQL equivalent IN statement using System.Linq.Dynamic?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to run an IN statement through Dynamic LINQ by using the Contains method.  When using the following code, it runs just fine:

```
var statuses = new List<string> { "Active" };
result = result.Where("@0.Contains(Status)", statuses.ToArray());
```

But when I switch it to an array of integers, I get an error:

```
var years = new List<int> { 2012 };
result = result.Where("@0.Contains(Year)", years.ToArray());
```

This is the error I receive using the later:

> No applicable method 'Contains' exists in type 'Int32'

Is there a way to do this without having to resort to using multiple OR statements to get around using the IN statement?

The fields in the database that these are looking up are nullable fields.  Is that was is causing the issue?  I switched it from int to int? and it still shows the same error.  Any suggestions?

Comment: IQueryable<IRecord> where IRecord mimics my database structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after some research, it seems that Contains doesn't work "out-of-the box". I'm really surprised when you say that your first query works. I tried it, and had the same error as with the "Int32" one.

You might find a workaround here :

http://blog.walteralmeida.com/2010/05/advanced-linq-dynamic-linq-library-add-support-for-contains-extension-.html

You need to modify the System.Linq.Dynamic library by yourselft, or download the sample project here :
http://walteralmeida.typepad.com/files/dynamiclinqextension.zip

But the article is maybe outdated now (don't know about System.Linq.Dynamic's evolution since 20109.

Comment: @snoluet right, I tested and got the same error. Seems to be a little bit more complicated, I edited my answer.

Comment: @snoluet did this solution work for you?  I'm getting exceptions

Answer (score 1):

The code is failing because of how you're using .Contains. Try this instead:

```
var years = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var result = result.Where(element => years.Contains(element));
```

Apologies for not recognizing you need to work in Dynamic Linq. From my understanding Contains is not supported in Dynamic Linq by default, but it is possible to extend the library to support it. Please take a look at this link by Walter Almedia that explains how to extend the library: [Extending DynamicLINQ to Support Contains](http://blog.walteralmeida.com/2010/05/advanced-linq-dynamic-linq-library-add-support-for-contains-extension-.html)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. However, I am trying to accomplish this with the System.Linq.Dynamic library.  This is being used with a query building system where I won't know the fields or values that are being queried.  I need something where the SQL can be built using strings like the dynamic linq library allows you to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use as follows,

```
var resultset = from x in years
                where x == yearTobeSelected
                select x;
```

or you can use `IEnumerable.Contains()` by having the list in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var statuses = new string[] { "Active" };
result = result.Where(r => statuses.Contains(r.Status));
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. However, I am trying to accomplish this with the System.Linq.Dynamic library. This is being used with a query building system where I won't know the fields or values that are being queried. I need something where the SQL can be built using strings like the dynamic linq library allows you to do.